# When is the blow up at a point "as large as possible"

Tags: algebraic-geometry, blowup

The blow up, $\widetilde{X}$ of an affine variety $X \subset \mathbb A^n$ at $f_1,...,f_m$ is the closure of $\Gamma_f = \{(x,f(x)) : x \in U \}$ in $X \times \mathbb P^{m-1}$ (where $U = X \backslash Z(f_1,...,f_m)$, $f(x) := (f_1(x),...,f_m(x))$, and assuming $U \neq \emptyset$).

But I have also seen a definition something like $\widetilde{X} = \{ (x,y) \in X \times P^{m-1} : x_i y_j = x_jy_i \}$ in the case where $f_i = x_i$, (that is, when we are blowing up at the origin).

There is an easy inclusion (the first into the second), but I've been trying to figure out if these two definitions agree in general.  And if they do, can anyone provide a reference?  (I'm pretty hazy on schemes so if it can be argued without them it would be appreciated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get the same thing so long as
$$(f_1,\ldots, f_m) = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$$
as ideals.  To see this, first note that your second definition is the same as the first in the case where your functions are the $x_i$ (which it appears you already have), and then use the fact that the $f_i$ generate the same ideal to write the $x_i$ as $k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$-linear combinations of the $f_j$.  This should give you your map in the other direction.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer.  Maybe I am slow, but I see only one direction of the equality for the $f_i = x_i$ case.  How do I know $x_iy_j = y_ix_j$ are sufficient to define the closure $\widetilde{X}$?  (certainly they are necessary).

Comment: Okay, suppose without loss of generality $x_1 \neq 0$.  We have $x_1 y_j = y_1 x_j$ for all $j$.  We cannot have $y_1 = 0$ or else we'd have $y_j = 0$ for all $j$.  Writing $\lambda := y_1/x_1$, we have $y_j = \lambda x_j$ for all $j$.

Comment: If I'm following you, you have just shown that a point in $(X \backslash Z(x_1,...,x_n)) \times \mathbb P^{m-1}$ satisfying the $x_i y_j = x_j y_i$ equations is also in $\Gamma$.  But I think we need that a point in $X \times \mathbb P^{m-1}$ satisfying the $x_i y_j = x_j y_i$ is in $\overline{\Gamma}$ (the closure in $X \times \mathbb P^{m-1}$).

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I misread your inital question; I thought you were taking $X = \mathbb{A}^n$ rather than an arbitrary subvariety of it.  It's not true in general that $\overline{\Gamma}$ will be cut out by the $x_i y_j - x_j y_i$ alone.  In particular, note that the entirety of $\{0\} \times \mathbb{P}^{n-1}$ is clearly cut out by those equations.  That's only contained in the blowup when $X = \mathbb{A}^n$.

Comment: Right, that was silly of me.  Thanks again!